# Ubuntu 18.04 not connecting to a particular wifi

Tags: wireless, router

I have an issue with connecting i ball Baton 1200AC WiFi router.I am able to connect Ubuntu 18.04 to TPLink Router but it is not able to connect to i ball Baton 1200ac WiFi router. My wireless-info.txt is at **https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XS66PP99ST/**

Comment: Are you trying to connect from laptop (using in-built wireless card) or using external usb wireless adapter? If you provide details on your laptop's wireless card, or external wireless adapter, someone will be able to help you better.

Comment: Since you can connect using TP-Link router, run this Wireless Info Script: github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info , as described in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205  It'll create "wireless-info.txt" file at the location it is run from; then edit your original post, and copy paste the output from that TXT file. Info about the script, as mentioned in the post, "we created at the Ubuntu Forums to collect all the most common information needed while masking all sensitive data."

Comment: I am trying to connect from hp laptop.

Comment: i have edited and link for wireless-info.txt is attached

Comment: Can you try connecting after changing wireless channel (like 6 or 11) in your i-ball baton router, and if it doesn't get connected, post the output of journalctl | grep <ssid>. Replace ssid with actual ssid of i-ball baton router.